# Macro to evaluate expression and create import

Tags: import, macros, nim-lang

This may seem odd and is perhaps impossible but I was wondering if there's a way to create a macro that evaluates the expression passed and performs an `import`.

I can get it to work easily enough if a string literal is the expression:

```
import macros
macro createImport(ex: expr): stmt =
  result = newNimNode(nnkImportStmt)
  result.add(ex)

createImport("strutils")

let a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
echo a.join("---") # using `join()` from the `strutils` module
```

But if a variable is passed, this of course will fail.

```
var s = "strutils"
createImport(s)
```

*(Note that the import could be a string path do a module.)*

I've attempted many adjustments to the macro and scoured the docs and source but I just can't find a way to get the actual value of the `ex: expr` to be useful in the `import`.

I can get the macro to create an `echo` call that reveals the string passed but any attempt to use it with the import ends up using the variable name itself.

I guess it makes since since it would seem that the value may not be available when the macro itself is evaluated. Is it possible to do this and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you need such a helper macro and whether it's a good idea, but the simplest way to achieve what you need is the following:

```
template my_import(x: static[string]) = import x

const x = "strutils"
my_import x
```

Comment: The helper macro was because the original macro couldn't (to my knowledge) utilize the value of the `expr` before the expansion. Any attempt to use it would end up just using the original variable name. But this looks interesting. I'm going to try the `static[string]`. I didn't remember that. There are a couple ways this could be called, so I'll mess around and check back. *Thanks!*

Comment: Oh... I see that requires a `const`. The example in my question is a simplification of a larger problem, and a `const` won't be a possibility. :-( Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: static[T] can be used with macros too to get the desired effect, but it requires something that can be evaluated at compile time (not strictly a const symbol). Nim is a compiled language, so obviously you won't be able to supply the imported module name at run-time.

Comment: The imports are based on some file system analysis while building the app, and the root of the analysis needs to be the file from which the macro would be called. But now that you've got me thinking about it, it won't work with macros because, of course, the expanded code is going to be invoked at runtime. There seems to be limitations on the API that can be used during compile time, so I may just need to do the filesystem stuff with `staticExec`.

Comment: *(Going to use your post as a sounding board. Feel free to ignore or chime in as you like.)*... So actually, all I need this for is the imports. The macros are expanded at compile time and the imports are read at compile time as well after the macro expansion (pretty sure), so it should do what I want if I can get it working. The file itself where the macro call is doesn't actually need to use anything. The only way I know to get the app root at compile time is with `instantiationInfo()` being called from the root file, so that's a key part of the macro.

Comment: Yes, you can use `currentSourcePath.splitPath.head` to get the current directory inside a macro. `staticExec` should get you where you want from there.

Comment: `currentSourcePath` called in the macro definition gives me the file where the macro exists and when called in the expanded macro code (via `newCall("currenSourcePath")`) gives me the path to the `...lib/core/macros.nim` file. This is a module that is imported into the application root where the macro is called.

Comment: ...`instantiationInfo(-1, true).filename` in the macro definition gives me `???` but gives a correct absolute path when called in expanded code. Going to see if I can do the traversal work in the expanded macro.

Comment: ...so it seems that *(bearing in mind I'm a bit of a novice on this stuff)* macro expansion happens during compilation, and when the macro is expanded, it's analysed to see if there were any `import` statements created, which the compiler then executes. ... No matter what route I take, the holdup is that I can't get the value out of an `expr` in the macro definition itself, so it can't be used as part of the definition (like with `newStrLitNode()`). Using `.staticExec` would be fine if only I could get the application root at compile time.

Comment: Ah, it's more useful to get the caller module path indeed. Here is a gist, showing how to do this:
https://gist.github.com/zah/8dd6ab8219db1037e0bd

It's a bug that `instantiationInfo` doesn't give correct results inside a macro. One alternative is to use `callsite().lineinfo`, but this doesn't expand to full paths (another thing to fix).

Comment: Thanks @zah. So I guess for the time being I'll use `staticExec("pwd")` and just be sure to be at the app root when compiling. That should hold me over until things are patched up. Thanks so much for all your help! I've learned a lot about using macros today! :-)

Comment: ...oh wait, your `workhorse/helper` does work. I was testing it wrong. I think that'll do the trick for me for now. Thanks again!